# Graph Basic linear inequality

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to graph a basic linear inequality (y < -2x + 5).

I started something. I could figure out how to graph y = -2x + 5.

In short what I'm trying to get:

[image]

What I currently have:

[image]

The code for what I have:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin=-5, xmax=5,
            ymin=-5, ymax=5,small,
            grid]
            
            \addplot [
            domain = -5:5,
            samples = 1000,blue,very thick] {-2*x+5} 
            node [pos=.65, right] {};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin=-5, xmax=5,
            ymin=-5, ymax=7,small, % changed
            grid]
            
            \addplot [dashed, % changed
            domain = -5:5,
            samples = 1000,blue,very thick] {-2*x+5} 
            node [pos=.65, right] {};
            \fill[red!30,opacity=.5] (-5,-5) rectangle (-1,7); % added
            \fill[red!30,opacity=.5] (-1,-5)--(5,-5)-- (-1,7); % added
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super helpful! I try messing around to learn how else I could shade based on what you had above (I think I got the hang of the shading. Like you did a rectangle and a triangle). Very very helpful! Thanks so much

Comment: You are wellcome!